# TypeScript intersection with arrays

Tags: typescript, types, lodash

I am using lodash `merge` to merge two objects. The types for lodash (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bab9c9aef2477d222f014a25ce86585af76c3a5c/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L1718) simply rely on intersection types which have some shortcomings when it comes to arrays.

Say I want to merge objects with these types

```js
interface One {
  str: string;
  arr: Array<{ foo: string }>;
}

interface Two {
  num: number;
  arr: Array<{ bar: string }>;
}
```

When these objects are merged with lodash `merge` the resulting shape is

```js
interface Merged {
  str: string;
  num: number;
  arr: Array<{ foo: string; bar: string }>;
}
```

But this is not how intersection types work (rationale [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11961#issuecomment-257444466)). What you end up with for the type of `arr` is `Array<{ foo: string; }> & Array<{ bar: string }>` which has this problem:

```js
declare const test: Array<{ foo: string }> & Array<{ bar: string }>;
test.forEach((item) => item.bar); // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ foo: string; }'.(2339)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3hkmBc8AgjDFAJ4A8A3vAGZJIGYwCWKA5vAL4B88AZERLlq8AEawmGVh248A3ACgcmAHT0YAUShgAFgAp9LHAFsAlPAC8fYyBOqJMM0qA)

Can a better type for `merge` be defined such that for arrays `Array<A>` and `Array<B>` you get `Array<A & B>` instead of `Array<A> & Array<B>`? It would have to be some kind of recursive mapped type, but I didn't have any luck writing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can create a type that normalizes arrays recursively.

```
type NomalizeArrays<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends any[] ? Array<NomalizeArrays<T[P][number]>> : NomalizeArrays<T[P]>
}
```

We can pass in any intersection in `T`. We mostly leave the structure alone except for arrays. For arrays we take `T[P][number]` which will be an intersection of the object types.

It seems t work as expected, let me know if you find any issues:

```
let r = _.merge({
    arr: [{ foo : "A"}],
    str: ""
},  {
    arr: [{ bar: "B"}],
    num: 1
})

r.arr.forEach(x => x.bar + x.foo);

let r2 = _.merge({
    arr: [{ outerA: "", nested: [{ foo: "" }]}]
}, {
    arr: [{ outerB: "", nested: [{ bar: "" }]}]
})

r2.arr.forEach(x => {
    x.outerA
    x.outerB
    x.nested.map(xx => xx.bar  +  xx.foo)
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=11&pln=12&pc=24#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gfQFzwBkkARKNACwGUMoMBLMAKEYwE8AHBAOSQFsoIdAF4gAgjBhRWaADwAVAHzwAvPADejeFvgBtAArw6KeAGsQrJADN4cgLr45+2-BAAPDCBTA08KClY6zgD88OKSrDI8-IIiYVKyjnq2OigArrwARiAwtgpK+FECwmIS8fJOCowAvsyMECBYMCo4AHS82QDmIAAUGtq+Evg6avCWSEjw+ABEolNVtgA0mtqYMNNT1Qtafdqwa7ojGbDTAEJzi8taabz4AIzVAJTMMC17LWMwAKJQYOTdriolK4WkcmgBqeDAsZIB4AbmY9UaACZmtg2p0ejstHshiMkKkPDBROstigQJgQMBcaNxut4PN5pt1JcBvthvB8YSTiT4GSKVSDvBQXSGbZHs8ka8JO8kF8fn8AcolFjIS1OdlRCzgeqYCctS0+R5gG0oOx-oqgcDQVoIZCoeMnlU4bUjITLD8EERSBRqLQGMz+u0YF15AB5DIAK3AGC2cko+JgYBACm6SEj0Yc4ajYBj8DQCaTDnjqUTIAeBT4RVipWkYfTOfgADIbMXSwp4YGMXXs7m4wWQLdY62k0iU2me5n67n8yWk7ci-3B3n+0iF7OQEjy-BCjESuEElno02W4vj3316OO9ogyG5Iec0PF4+L8-SwBmMdTyc9rYz0vzk91yXP8RzXUskV-fs3zApM3y3HdijiWs7ynM9hwHNCV0w9cPyvLQbxAbto1fOcSI3Mi3zIgAWT8Jxse9p0XGCB0gi9mIg5ccOYyjONLKjmKo+DK13JCD1Q5tz3-bDwOk2DZJAGi8PgAjUy-Xx-C2FotKQDByA1YM0HwPwAlsLdjPhGogA)